# dominated convergence theorem application

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove or disprove this statement: 
if $f_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are integrable functions with $f_n \to 0$ pointwise and $|f_n(x)| \le \frac{1}{|x| + 1}$ for all $n$, $x$, then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int\limits_{\mathbb R} f_n = 0$.

According to [Dominated Convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) 
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int\limits_{\mathbb R} f_n = \int\limits_{\mathbb R} f$.

I don't know how one can show that it is equal to 0 or not. I am stuck...need some help

Comment: According to the stated convergence of $f_n$, what is $f$?

Comment: How are you applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem?  What integrable function dominates all $f_n$?

Comment: it is the function g(x)=1/(|x|+1)

Comment: @Anna that function is not integrable.

Comment: does this mean that I can not apply dominated convergence theorem? @breeden

Comment: @Anna right.  It means that you can't apply the dominated convergence theorem.  But that _doesn't_ mean that the statement is false.  It just means that your original approach won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the functions $$f_n(x) = \frac{\chi_{[n,n^2]}(x)}{1+x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What happens if
$$ f_n(x) = \frac{n}{  (|x| +n)^2 } $$

Comment: can I use [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) ?

Comment: calculate the integral...

Comment: after taking the limit of integral is it equal to zero?

Comment: you should find that $\int f_n dx = 2$ for all $n$. Thus this is a counter example to the statement.

Comment: could you help me with calculating the integral please?

Comment: This is a first year calculus exercise... I suggest having a look at your past notes. i.e what is $\int \frac{dx}{x^2}$

Comment: ooops sorry, I was trying to calculate n/(abs(x)+n) didn't see the 2nd power

Comment: but I can not see how the value of the integral will be 2.